# Java Error: cannot resolve method split()

Tags: java, string, intellij-idea, split, compiler-errors

I am trying to get user input into a String array and wanted to use the `string.split()` method but for some reason, my IntelliJ is telling me, that it cannot resolve the method 'split()'.

```java
package com.Practice;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = sc.nextLine();

        String[] splittedString = input.split();
    }
}
```

I dont think, that there is a problem with my code, mayby with my IDE or Java version, but im no expert at this stuff.
When I try to run the program it throws me this error:

```
Error:(10, 40) java: no suitable method found for split(no arguments)
    method java.lang.String.split(java.lang.String,int) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method java.lang.String.split(java.lang.String) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
```

Comment: You need to apply a regex as parameter for the `split()` function. For example, if you want to split words separated by a space, you can use `split("\\s")`, `\\s` meaning all whitespaces, end of line and tab characters.

Comment: You also need to read the error message, which tells you precisely what is wrong (i.e. you're calling split() without any argument, and both of the split() methods require arguments), and to read the javadoc of the classes and methods that you're using, which explain what the methods expect as argument and how they work: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-

Comment: Also, since you're using IntelliJ, code completion would allow you to find out what arguments are required: put your cursor inside the parentheses, and hit Ctrl-P or Cmd-P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java really doesn't have a `String#split` method that takes no arguments. You need to split the string by a regex, such as `\\s` (which mean splitting by a whitespace):

```
String[] splittedString = input.split("\\s");
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in some of the other answers, `String.split()` in Java requires an input, if you intend to apply something to every character or create an array of characters you'll need to iterate for example.

```
private String myCoolString = "myCoolString";
private char[] chars = new char[myCoolString.length()];
//array of primitive chars
for( int i = 0; i < myCoolString.length();i++){
    chars[i] = myCoolString.charAt(i);
}

// List of boxed Characters (Java 8+, the above can be used to do this too)
List<Character> charList =
        myCoolString
                .chars()
                .mapToObj(e->(char)e)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an argument in **split** method. check split method [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = sc.nextLine();

    String[] splittedString = input.split(" ");

}
}
```